# How to Read all the information in a Microsoft WindowsInstaller Transform File Using C# Code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, windows-installer, transform

Can somebody help me getting a sample code for getting all the information in a Transform File? Things I need to fetch is ,

1. Check whether the given Table is present in the mst
2. If Present, Check whether there is any records in the table.
3. Get only the changes in the MST and write them in a log file writing their corresponding Table name, Column name and the Value.
4. Is there any way to get all the information in the MST including the MSI table records?
5. How to accomplish this using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller; ?
6. How to Use using or Dispose or IDisposable in this context?
   Am using,
   Visual Studio 2010 C# .net Windows Forms Application.

Note: I am trying to create a new msi or mst. Am just want to validate a MSI or MST which was already available.

Give me a sample code since am so new to c#

Comment: I suggest looking at the MSI VBScript samples/tools included in the Windows SDK. There are a lot of examples and tools for manipulating MSI/MST files - and once you understand how the tools and API functions work, porting the VBScript to C# should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

At the C/C++ level, I would recommend [MsiDatabaseApplyTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370074.aspx) with an included flag in `iErrorConditions` of `MSITRANSFORM_ERROR_VIEWTRANSFORM`. This places all the information you need in the [_TransformView table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372926.aspx). I'll leave it up to you to figure out how this API is exposed in the language or library you're using.

Note that some parts of what you ask are not really valid; MST files do not seem to contain tables or table records per se. At the very least, there are no APIs that expose them other than the approach I referenced above.